# Error `Unable to find a template property named $schema.` when trying to decompile JSON into Bicep

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I'm playing with Azure Bicep and I was expecting that I can take practically any ARM JSON template and translate it into Bicep. I'm intentionally using the word "translate" instead of "decompile" here, because the JSON template was not originally created with Bicep, so it was not compiled from Bicep to JSON in the first place.

I'm creating a VM deployment in the Azure Portal and when it's successfully deployed I download the JSON template (deployment.json and deployment_operations.json).

Then I run the following command:

```
bicep decompile deployment.json
```

The command fails with the following error message:

```
/deployment.json: Decompilation failed with fatal error "[1:1]: Unable to find a template property named $schema."
```

What should I do to resolve this error?

Bicep CLI version 0.13.1 (e3ac80d678).

PS The VM deployment is the simplest possible Windows Server VM with no data disks and extra features. Created via Azure Portal by clicking Next-Next-Create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I've found the solution when writing the question. I was downloading and trying to decompile a wrong file.

The problem was that I was downloading the `deployment.json` file instead of an actual template file `template.json`. You need to click Download on the Template tab.

So instead of downloading the from the Overview tab, click the **Template** tab and then click **Download**. Or use the [`Save-AzResourceGroupDeploymentTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/save-azresourcegroupdeploymenttemplate) PowerShell cmdlet.

[image: Download-Json-Template]

Similar problem, same solution: https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/5237